# What is the difference between “In case” and “if” in the context here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, if

> In case/if Ghalib keeps on weeping like this, then o the earthians, just watch these settlements that they will have become desolate!

This is an Urdu couplet by Mirza Ghalib which I translated here. I want to say that he is still weeping and if he continues to weep like this in the future, then o the earthians, you will see that these settlements will have become desolate. So dose ‘if’ describe he is still weeping, or should I use ‘in case’ instead?

Answer (score 1):

*In case* usually refers to being prepared for a possible problem or emergency - "I'll take my umbrella in case it rains".

Your quotation appears to be a prediction - what will happen if someone who is weeping continues to do so - so *if* is the appropriate choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would use *in case*:

> In case of fire, do not use elevator

Here, you can’t use if:

> If fire, do not use elevator

Because you aren’t saying in a *case of fire*, rather just *fire*, which doesn’t specify what you actually mean by fire.

Also, ‘In case’ can imply that it’s a ‘case’ of something, meaning it may happen multiple times.

In this example, I would use ‘if’ because otherwise it sounds like you’re warning people of something that may happen multiple times, as I said before.

Comment: What I believe you are saying is that "in case of" can form part of a noun phrase, while "if" requires a verb of some kind. You could, for example say "If there's a fire do not use elevator" - though it would be unusual. But there is the added difference that "in case" usually accompanies a warning. For example "If you are wearing a life jacket you will float in water" simply states what is a fact. But "In case you fall in the water you should wear a life jacket" describes why it is advisable.